# Is there a way to separate elements of user input? (i.e. - entering a date as mm/dd/yyy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, datetime

I am having trouble breaking apart elements of a date into their distinct parts for a homework assignment. Say a user inputs a date as mm/dd/yyyy. If I append their input to an empty list, is there a way to separate it within that list? This would be very convenient. We are restricted to loops and defining our own functions -- no importing other functions.

Comment: `myDate.split('/')` will return a list of with each section.

Answer (score 2):

If you are appending the dates to a list (Ex: `myDates`) you can do something like:

```
myDates = ['01/02/2017', '03/04/2018']
myDates = [tuple(date.split('/')) for date in myDates]
for month, day, year in myDates:
    print("Month: {} Day: {} Year{}".format(month, day, year))
```

**Output:**

```
Month: 01 Day: 02 Year: 2017
Month: 03 Day: 04 Year: 2018
```